# Why does Extract add extra {} to the result and what is best way to remove them

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

When I type the following

```
lis = {1, 2};
pos = Position[lis, 1];
result = Extract[lis, pos]
```

the result is always a list.

```
{1}
```

another example

```
lis = {{1}, {2}};
pos = Position[lis, {1}];
result = Extract[lis, pos]

{{1}}
```

Mathematica always adds an extra {} in the result. What would be the best way to remove this extra {}, other than applying Flatten[result,1] each time? And is there a case where removing these extra {} can cause a problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you are asking why

```
lis = {{1}, {2}};
pos = Position[lis, {1}];
result = Extract[lis, pos]
```

returns

```
{{1}}
```

rather than

```
{1}
```

The answer is, I think, simple: `Position[lis,{1}]` gives the position at which `{1}`, not `1` appears in `lis`; when you then go and look at that position using `Extract`, you do indeed get `{1}` which is then wrapped in a list (which is exactly what happened in the first case, when you looked for `1` and obtained `{1}` as a result; just replace `1` by `{1}`, because that is now what you are asking for.

To see this more clearly, try

```
lis = {f[1], f[2]};
pos = Position[lis, f[1]];
result = Extract[lis, pos]
```

which gives

```
{f[1]}
```

The point here is that `List` in `{1}` (which is the same as `List[1]` if you check look at the `FullForm`) before was just a head, like `f` here. Should mathematica have remove `f` here? If not, then why should it have removed the innermost `List` earlier?

And finally, if you really want to remove the inner `{}` in your second example, try

```
lis = {{1}, {2, {1}}};
pos = Position[lis, {1}];
result = Extract[lis, pos, #[[1]] &]
```

giving

```
{1, 1}
```

EDIT: I am becoming puzzled with some of the answers here. If I do

```
lis = {{1}, {2, {1, 2, {1}}}};
pos = Position[lis, 1];
result = Extract[lis, pos]
```

then I get

```
{1, 1, 1}
```

in `result`. I only get the extra brackets when I actually obtain the positions of `{1}` in `pos` instead of the positions of `1` (and then when I look at those positions, I find `{1}`). Or am I missing something in your question?

Answer (score 6):

You probably realise this, but `Position` and `Extract` return lists because the requested values may be found in more than one position.  So in general, removing the outer brackets doesn't make sense.

If you are sure the result is a singleton list, using `Flatten` would destroy information if the element is itself a list.  For example,

```
Position[{{1}},1]
```

gives a list whose sole element is a list.  So in this case, using `Extract` would make more sense.

Even so, there are many situations where Mathematica treats {x} very differently to x, as in

```
Position[1,1]
Position[{1},1]
```

which have very different results.  So whether you can remove the outer braces from a one-member list depends on what you plan to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**: You should *probably* use `First@Position[...]`

Long answer:
Lets separate the question to 2 parts:

#### Why do you have the extra `{}` in the result for `Position`?

i.e. why:

```
lis = {1, 2};
Position[lis, 1]
```

returns `{{1}}`?

This is in order to work consistently with n-dimensional list, that may have the requested values in more than one position. For example:

```
lis = {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 1}};
Position[lis, 1]
```

returns `{{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {3, 3}}`

which is a list of the coordinates the result is found in.
So in your case:

```
lis = {1, 2};
Position[lis, 1]
```

return `{{1}}`, as in: we found your requested value one time, in the coordinate-set `{1}`.

Now, a lot of times Mathematica assume that there might be a list of solutions (for example, in `Solve`), but the user know that he expect only one. A suitable code to this in your case will be `First@Position[...]`. this will return the first (and, assumebly, only) element in the list of positions -- 
So, if you are sure that the element you are searching for exist only once in the list and want to know where, use this way.

#### Why do you have the extra `{}` in the result for `Extract`?

`Extract` can work in two different ways.

If I'm doing `Extract[{{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, e, h}}, {1, 2}]`
I will get `b`, so extract with a 1 dimensional list of is just choosing and returning this element. In fact, `Extract[lis, {1, 2}]` is equal to `lis[[1, 2]]`

If I'm doing `Extract[{{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, e, h}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}]`
I will get `{b, h}`, so extract with a 2 dimensional list is choosing and returning a list of elements.

In your case(s), you are doing `Extract[lis, {{1}}]`, as in: give me a list containing only the element `lis[[1]]`. The result is always this element in a list, which is the extra `{}`

Comment: There is a problem with your solution. If I use First@Position[...] then it will not work all the time. Here is an example: First@Position[{1,2}, 99]. So one has to check first to see if Position did not return {} before using this method, which is not good. But Flatten[Position[{1, 2}, 99], 1] will work even if Position returns {} or not.

Comment: yep. This trick works if the element exist only and exactly once in the code.

Comment: I think/hope I explained pretty well why does Mathematica add the extra `{}` to your result. In order to say what's the best way to remove them, you need to give more information - what do you try to do (what's the start and end point)? do you expect 'strange' cases in your input (like more or less than 1 found element)? and how do you want the program to handle them?